# jqGrid problem displaying the contents of the grid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start). I am loading the data into the grid from the server side. The server responds back to the client with the following data.

```
{
    "page":"1",
    "total":"1",
    "totalrecords":"3",
     "rows":[
         {"name":"query-2","desc":"patton","id":2},
         {"name":"query-=576","desc":"kumar","id":3},
         {"name":"query-=57664","desc":"krishna","id":4}
     ]
}
```

My jsonReader and other data looks like this

```
  jsonReader : {
      cell : "",
      id : "0"
  },
  datatype : "json",
  mtype : "POST",
  url : "loadData.htm",
  colModel : [ {
          name : "name",
          index : "name",
          sorttype : "String",
          title : false,
          resizable : false,
          align : "left"
      },
      {
          name : "id",
          index : "id",
          hidden:"true"
      },
      {
          name : "desc",
          index : "desc",
          title : false,
          align : "left"
      },
```

As I have said I am getting the response back to the client. But the grid is unable to show the contents, but it is displaying empty data.

BTW, I am sending data as a string. Is it required to send the data as a JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't included definition of the grid (at least `colModel`). So I could not be sure about the usage of "id". Nevertheless I suppose that you should use the following `jsonReader`

```
jsonReader : {
   records: "totalrecords",
   cell: "",
   repeatitems: false
}
```

Moreover I recommend you to use some other extension as HTM for the `url` parameter (currently you have `url: "loadData.htm"`). It is important that `jQuery.ajax` used by jqGrid could try to guess the content type of the data or the web server could place explicitly in the HTTP header the "Content-Type" other as "application/json" which can follow to problems.

See demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Phani.htm).

Comment: @Oleg problem was solved I have made changes to the json reader and it worked.Thank you very much

Comment: @Oleg I am unable to do sorting on the client side.Can you please suggest changes so that I would be able to sorting on the client side?

Comment: @Phani: You can enable local sorting, paging and filtering with `loadonce:true` parameter which I used in my demo. You should understand, that the parameter switch the `datatype` of the grid to 'local' after the first load. If you will need to reload the grid from the server you will have to reset `datatype:'json'` before reloading the grid. Just search for `loadonce:true` to read more information about.

Comment: @Oleg I even tried that approach but I am unable to use paging with that.Say I am using onPaging : function() {
  $(this).setGridParam({datatype:'json'});
  }

Comment: @Phani: Sorry, but I don't understand what you really want to do. The sorting on the client side has sense only if the server return **all** the grid data (for all pages). Only in the case you will see correct page of data after the local sorting. But in the case you need not use `onPaging`.

Comment: @Oleg I have around 900 records to be displayed and I am displaying 25 at a time.According to the requirement I need to sort only these 25 records that are been displayed.

Comment: @Phani: Sorry, but I don't understand the requirement. If you explain exactly your customer what it mean the customer will fix his requirements. What I don't understand is why you not do sorting on the server side? It is more easier as to implement the paging of data. On the other side 900 records is not so much. Look at the demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/1000paged.htm with 1000 rows. It work very quickly. The loading of 900 records from the server is typically very quickly also.

Comment: @Oleg fine I will try it out with the customer once again.Thank you very much